# why is this Query creating seemingly random results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This makes no sense to me, but this query display some records in full some in partial and some in a single line.  With seemingly no rhythm or reason.  Even worse when I run the query in MySql it works just fine with no issues at all. Currently I am thinking it is a demon and/or super demon.

```
$sql =  "SELECT phonenumber,date,dataplan AS currentplan, SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata2 WHERE email='".($_POST['email'])."' GROUP BY phonenumber,date";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$header_printed = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row['phonenumber']) {
        if ($header_printed === false) {

            echo "   
            <table id='display'>
            <tr>
            <th>Phone Number:</th>
            <th>Data Plan:</th>
            <th>Data Usage This Period:</th>
            <th>Remaining:</th>
            <th>Date Reporting:</th>
            </tr>";

            $header_printed = true;
        }
    }
} 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phonenumber'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>".$row['currentplan'] . "MB</td> ";
    echo "<td>".ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2) . "MB</td> ";
    echo "<td>".($row['currentplan'] - ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2)) . "MB</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Any thoughts would be one more than I have right now!

Comment: Are the data well-formed in your database?  No stray newlines at the end of fields?  Can you check with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Can you provide a structure sample of the table so we can test and see what exactly is the problem? Also, you're creating a <table> tag inside your loop. Generally you want create the table tag before the loop.

Comment: Why are you querying the database with the same query twice and making two result sets? Why do you have this line `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` and do nothing with it (it will end up just advancing your result set pointer)?

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: @MikeBrant  That was it! I didn't need it, and it was causing an issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just notice that the  is inside the loop which is resulting in the creation of multiple tables, this could be a reason, another note, why are you making the same query twice, that's a useless over head on the db engine ?! and a last note, NEVER EVER use the user input directly in your query without cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are running the same query twice. On this line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You fetch the first result row of the result set, yet you don't actually do anything with it at all.

You mix your usage of `$query` and `$result` as well.

You likely need to output your table header before you loop through the result set. Then loop through the result set once, outputting each row.